# lightdm doesn't work after installing lightdm-unity-greeter on arch

Tags: arch-linux, lightdm

I was using `lightdm` with the `lightdm-gtk-greeter` just fine, however I tried to install the unity greeter and now it shows me a black screen with a blinking cursor (I have to ctr+alt+1 and login through the shell to get in)

I'm not sure why it doesn't work, the installation completed without any issues, can anyone point me in the right direction? Let me know if I should post anything that'd help debug the problem.

UPDATE: I just tried installing the pantheon greeter and got the same error, webkit greeter works fine though

Comment: Showing the contents of `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` & `/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log` would be useful in assisting you.

Comment: Thanks, here's [my lightdm.log](http://pastebin.com/m32BWZJg) file and [x-0.log](http://pastebin.com/Ysv5dF3S) after trying to loggin using `lightdm-pantheon-greeter`

Comment: `[+0.20s] DEBUG: Failed to load session file /usr/share/xgreeters/lightdm-pantheon-greeter.desktop: No such file or directory` is your problem. could you pastebin the output of `ls /usr/share/xgreeters` or `pacman -Ql $packagethatinstalledlightdm-panthron-greeter`?

Comment: `ls /usr/share/xgreeters/` outputs `lightdm-gtk-greeter.desktop  pantheon-greeter  pantheon-greeter.desktop` looks like there's actually no `lightdm-pantheon-greeter.desktop` should I rename the existing `pantheon-greeter.desktop` ?

Comment: Oh actually I changed the `greeter-session` variable in my `lightdm.conf` file to `pantheon-greeter` and it started to work, thanks!